# Can we extract view data into insert scripts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using SQL server and I need to extract the data in view to insert queries. I have used Generate Scripts -> Data Only option in Tasks to do it.

I was able to extract only the create statement of the view in that file not the insert queries. When I tried the same thing on a table instead of view, I am able to extract the insert queries.

Then, I wrote the data of the view into a table and extracted the insert queries. Am I missing anything here? Or is it a known behavior?

Comment: Hi Jens,

I am able to extract insert queries for tables but not for Views. I used the same method that was specified in the link that you have provided.

Comment: I tried writing that view's data into a temp table and tried extracting. It worked. But, I don't why it is not working for views directly without using a temp table. Do we have any known reason that why this extraction is not possible in views?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Yes, this is a known behavior and works as intended. Since a view is nothing like a table, the results can be very different each execution and are also not stored anywhere on your storage. It wouldn't make a lot of sense for a scripting tool to script results of a view if you can script the view itself and the tables & content it links to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * INTO ATable FROM AView
```

and then script out the table it created...

The reason you cannot script data from the view is because the view does not contain any data its self, it is just a saved query... so you can script its definition, but it does not make sense to say the view's data, as the data the view presents is actually in some tables, not the view. Saving the RESULTS of the view into a table, makes it into data.

Comment: I tried the same and it worked fine. But, Why the same method is not possible in views directly without using temp tables?

Comment: because the view does not contain any data, it is just a saved query... so you can script its definition, but it does not make sense to say the view's data, as the data the view presents is actually in some tables. Saving the RESULTS of the view into a table, makes it into data

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the comment? Will close this. If you are okay, I will update it.